# How to submit a bug report to Ubuntu about Raspberry Pi5 fan speed?

Tags: raspberrypi, fan, 23.10

Fan speed control does not work on Ubuntu 23.10 due to they are using an old `bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb` file.

That updated file is present in the raspberry repo
https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb

Will Ubuntu guys ever update that file?
Is there a way to submit a bug report to try to mitigate this problem as soon as possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 14):

Good job diagnosing the problem.

The updated version is in 24.04 ([source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+changelog)):

> 6.7.0-1001.1
> Published in noble-proposed on 2024-02-01
>
> ...
> ARM: dts: bcm2712-rpi-5-b: Add fan speed dtparams
> ...

However, nobody has yet asked for the fix to be applied to 23.10.

You will be the first, helping everybody else.

Open a terminal and run `ubuntu-bug linux` to start the process of filing the bug report for 23.10.

Let the kernel engineers set the priority. Priority usually goes to issues causing data loss or crashes so give them facts and avoid hype.